# Bluehost Shared Hosting + Bitbucket Webhooks

Tags: php, python-2.7, bitbucket, webhooks, shared-hosting

I have tried two paths to getting Bitbucket webhooks working on a Bluehost shared hosting website and neither work.

The first involves using [myWebHook.php](https://github.com/mexitek/myWebHook) but I had issues with a missing payload.  How do I create this payload in the most simple way and add it to my directory so that myWebHook.php will work?

Second, I tried to go through [BitBucket tutorial on creating webhooks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/tutorial-create-and-trigger-a-webhook-747606432.html) but that didn't work because I'd get the following error:

```
ImportError: This platform lacks a functioning sem_open implementation, therefore, the required synchronization primitives needed will not function, see issue 3770.
```

Which I can't figure out how to fix.  Additionally, I can't figure out how to install `ngrok` on a Bluehost server.  Does anyone have any tips around this?

Additionally, if someone just got this working in another way, can someone please post that methodology?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can't do it with webhooks. For webhooks, your server-side script pull code from bitbucket. You must have priveleges to run `git pull` on web server. But if it shared webhosting, then it likely impossible.

Can you enter on your hosting by ssh and run command `git pull`?

Maybe easy way is use [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp)?

`git ftp push --user <user> --passwd <password> ftp://host.example.com/public_html`

PS: Bitbucket have new feature - pipelines. You can try use it. It is docker container which can do something when you doing push.